# Python cassandra-driver: The C extension needed to use libev was not found

Tags: python, cassandra, libev, cextension

I have Cassandra python driver version 2.5.1 installed with all required dependencies that is libev4, libev-dev, gcc, python-dev. However I am getting following error while importing `LibevConnection`

> "The C extension needed to use libev was not found. This probably
>   means that you didn't have the required build dependencies when
>   installing the driver"

I tried reinstalling and even installed latest version of the driver with no success.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What OS are you installing this on?

Comment: @mikea Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked I had all the dependencies installed but probably not when I installed the driver.
Before I tried reinstalling I tried installing newest version which made conflict with existing installation.

**So the problem was:** Not having dependency installed before installing python driver and then multiple installation of the driver.

**Solution** Remove all the version of Cassandra python driver completely from the system (Delete the relevant eggs). Make sure you have all the [dependencies installed](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#c-extensions). After that simply install the required version.